# React Router v4 NavLink active route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to port my project from using v3 of `react-router` to v4 of what is now called `react-router-dom`. Now the problems arise when I have a MenuBar component, which is completely separate from the routing logic (as you'd expect), because it will show the exact same links whatever the current path may be. Now that worked all nicely with v3, but now when I'm using `NavLink`, which has the same `activeClassName` property, the active route does not update on the NavBar, only on refresh. That seems a bit dumb, so there must be a way around this.

```js
export default @inject('ui') @observer class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className={ styles.wrapper }>
          <Sidebar />
          <main className={ `${styles.main} ${!this.props.ui.menuOpen && styles.closed}` }>
            <Route exact path="/" component={ HomePage } />
            <Route path="/signup" component={ SignUpPage } />
            <Route path="/login" component={ LoginPage } />
            <Route path="/about" component={ AboutPage } />
          </main>
          <footer className="site-footer"></footer>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

The above is my main App logic and as you can see the routes are nested, but the Router itself wraps around the whole component.

What should I add to make them work again? (They do work properly on page refresh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your usage of the `@observer` decorator, it appears that you are using `mobx-react`. The thing to understand about `observer` is that it implements `shouldComponentUpdate` to optimize rendering performance. That `sCU` call will look at the current and next props, and if there is no difference, it will not re-render. This is a problem because by default, React Router uses the context to pass data and relies on elements re-rendering to get the updated values, but `observer`'s `sCU` has no way to detect context changes.

The way that you can get around this is by passing the `location` object as a prop to the component that is wrapped by `observer`. Then, when the location changes, `observer`'s `shouldComponentUpdate` will detect the difference and re-render.

You can see the [blocked updates guide](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was indeed suspecting MobX, because currently only the navigation menu is hooked up to it. I also contemplated passing the location as a prop, but figured there must be a more elegant way to do it, because that way I'll need to do it with each component that should update with routes and store changes too.

Comment: Thank you again, for the answer as you did point me to the right direction. I ended up removing the `observer` logic from most of my components as they did not really need it and it freed the components from being changed exclusively when MobX intends to.