# ActiveStyle in NavLink is not working properly in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I referred many links describing this same problem. Some of them are 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752430/react-router-v4-navlink-active-route) and [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md). I just started react and finding it very difficult to understand what's been explained over there. I followed the tutorial [building react applications with idiomatic redux code](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-filtering-redux-state-with-react-router-params). In that the router version used is old. I updated to 4 and got this problem. My code is below.

```
const Root = ({ store }) => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Route path="/:filter?" component={App} />
        </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AddTodo />
                <VisibleTodoList />
                <Footer location={this.props.location}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const Footer = ({ location }) => (
    <p>
        Show :{" "}
        <FilterLink location={location} filterValue="all">
            All
        </FilterLink>{" "}
        <FilterLink location={location} filterValue="active">
            Active
        </FilterLink>{" "}
        <FilterLink location={location} filterValue="completed">
            Completed
        </FilterLink>
       </p>
);

const FilterLink = ({ filterValue, children, location }) => {
    return (
        <NavLink
            to={filterValue === "all" ? "" : filterValue}
            activeStyle={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "red" }}
        >
            {children}
        </NavLink>
    );
};
```

This code is making the url in browser to change accordingly. But the style is not updated. For all operation the Link "All" is red.

I am in a understanding that passing the location props (as per the explanation [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md)) will make the component to re render and the style will gets updated (Please correct if I am wrong here). But it didn't happen. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured the mistake. The problem lies here

```
const FilterLink = ({ filterValue, children }) => {
    return (
        <NavLink
            exact
            to={filterValue === "all" ? "/" : `/${filterValue}`}
            activeStyle={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "red" }}
        >
            {children}
        </NavLink>
    );
};
```

> The `"to"` props must be provided with the `"/"` at the beginning as shown above.

I missed this earlier. This solved my problem. No need to pass location props also. In the tutorial he used without "/" in the FilterLink component. Since I am using new version that code didn't work.

Comment: Thank you @shanmugharaj ! That fixed this issue !   The other issue is for updating the todos on clicking the links.  There's no update when clicking on a NavLink with react-router 4.  But it works with react-router 2 and Link.     Did you get that working with NavLink ?